# Python Linked list new node

Tags: python, linked-list

```
def insert_beginning(self, new_value):    #initialising new value
    new_node = Node(new_value)            #giving new value attribute to Node() for the new_node
    new_node.set_next_node(self.head_node)
    self.head_node = new_node
```

I did not understand the third line of code. Can anyone please explain me this line of code what its meaning is?

```
new_node.set_next_node(self.head_node)
```

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  You're asking us to teach you the meaning of an arbitrary function you failed to include.  Also, please explain *exactly* what you don't understand from the output you get when you trace this code.  Include that trace in your MRE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please provide all the **relevant** functions so that the community can help you, such as you're missing a `Node()` Function, this way it is easy for the community to find bugs if any. Assuming that `Node()` works the following explains your doubt.

> The line `new_node.set_next_node(self.head_node)` means you are now setting the next link value of newly formed node to the previous head value, this means your previous head node is now the second element in the linked list, so you're just setting the next link value to that previous head. Also third line means that you're updating the head pointer to newly inserted node, since you have inserted at the beginning of the list which is why you have to update the head node.

Image credits[GFG](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-set-2-inserting-a-node/)

[image: Insertion at the head position of linked list]